# Can I embed a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage or ContentView into a Wpf Window for quickly working with UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms

I have a WPF App that is currently just a window with a backing viewmodel, the viewmodel has a VisualElement property from Xamarin.Forms, that property is set with a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage in a .Net Standard 2.0 library, that VisualElement is attempting to be displayed in a ContentPresenter however I just get a type name in my window (as expected). The ContentPage is the one i'll be working with, but rather than always building on the Hyper-V emulator, i'd prefer to just quickly see my changes to UI and functionality in a window on my desktop.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  [Xamarin Forms Embedding](https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-xamarin-native/) allows you to do this.